# IFrame Resizable, but not Draggable with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have an iframe displaying "iframetarget.html" (for now just a blank red page for testing purposes).  I want to be able to resize it, as well as drag it around without constraint.  I used JQuery to make it resizable, and this worked.  Then, I added .draggable, and it fails to work.  Can you see what I'm doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<style>
  #iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: none;    
  background: #eee ;
  z-index: 1;
}
  #resizable {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  z-index: 9;
}
</style>

<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#resizable').resizable({
      start: function(event, ui) {
        $('iframe').css('pointer-events','none');
         },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        $('iframe').css('pointer-events','auto');
      }
  });
  });
</script>

<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#resizable').draggable();
  });
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="resizable">
  <iframe src="iframetarget.html" id="iframe">
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Wrap another div as a drag container. and set the draggable on that div element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing the click is going to the page in the iframe instead of being caught by your div. Resizable automatically add handles so that's why it works. You can add a handle to your draggable or simply put a border. For testing purpose, you'll see that your actual code works if you change your css to:

```
#iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: solid 10px black;    
  background: #eee ;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Then click on the border and it'll drag.

Or you add a small div that works as a handle:
http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-handle

Answer (score 0):

I had a familiar problem, dragging iFrames with jQueryUi (I've used a dialog and it was only possible to drag it holding the title bar). My solution was using ajax. Try that other way of "including another page":

```
function loadiframe(){

  var xmlhttp;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }else{
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
      document.getElementById("resizable").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","iframetarget.html",true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

If you run `loadiframe();` the content of `iframetarget` will be load to the #resizable element. Be careful using HTML, CSS and JavaScript in both pages, an iFrame just displays the other page in your one, but this will get the source code of `iframetarget.html` an add it into the div. You won't need HTML-declaration, `html`-, `head`- and `body`-tags in the iframetarget-file.